# Flink could not recovered from checkpoint after the Jobmanager was restarted

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running flink cluster on Docker-compose with 1 jobmanager and 1 taskmanager. I tested the mechanism of checkpoint by restart the container of Jobmanager. But I found the state was not restore properly. On the other hand, when I restarted the container of TaskManager, it worked perfectly.
Is that worked by design? And how could I recover the job from checkpoint when the JobManager is restarted?

Comment: Which checkpoin storage you using : JobManagerCheckpointStorage or FileSystemCheckpointStorage ? Don't you think when you restarting docker container it flushes checkpoints with it ?

Comment: I am using FileSystemCheckpointStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink requires that you configure High Availability in order to recover from job manager failures. The details of how to go about this depend on how your cluster is deployed: you can either setup Zookeeper to manage this, or rely on Kubernetes. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/ha/overview/ for details.

Comment: David, thanks for your answer.
In other words, checkpoint was not designed for the JobManager failure, is that right?

Comment: Correct. Checkpoints are for recovering from task manager failures. Job managers have state about which jobs are being executed, where their checkpoints are stored, etc. This info needs to be stored somewhere recoverable -- which is the role of Flink's high availability storage service.

Comment: It's helpful, thanks a lot.